# Comparing two time series

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-series

With two arrays of times A and B, we can define "matches" in different ways:

- divide a time range in bins of time and check for A and B times that fit in each bin.
- set a coincidence criteria for A (or B), like +/- 1 hour. Then for each time in A, get times in B that meet the coincidence criteria.

So far I have used the first solution. The steps I go through are:

For a time range going from t0 to tf, and a given time setp, I will
have (tf-t0)/time_step bins (rounded up as I don't mind if the last bin exceeds tf), first I get indices of times in A that fit in each bin:

```
span = (tf-t0)/time_step
tmin = t0
tempA = [[] for i in range(span)]
for i in range(span):
    tmax = tmin+time_step
    times = A[(A>=tmin) & (A<tmax)]
    times_ID=np.nonzero(np.in1d(A,times))[0]
    tempA[i] = [j for j in times_ID]
    tmin = tmax
```

Then I get the indices of times in B that fit in each bin for which we know there are times from A:

```
tmin = t0
tempB = [[] for i in range(span)]
for i in range(span):
    tmax=tmin+time_step
    if len(tempA[i])>0:
        times = B[(B>=tmin) & (B<tmax)]
        if len(times)>0:
            times_ID = np.nonzero(np.in1d(B,times))[0]
            tempB[i] = [j for j in times_ID]
    tmin=tmax
```

Finally for both temp lists, I get rid of the empty bins. And I also get rid of the bins for which the corresponding bins in the other list is empty:

```
tpA=[i for i in tempA if i!=[] and tempB[tempA.index(i)]!=[]] # Matching indices for data in A
tpB=[i for i in tempB if i!=[] and tempA[tempB.index(i)]!=[]] # Matching indices for data in B
```

The loops to fill the time bins can be very time consuming. And I am not sure how to make them more efficient.
Is there a smarter way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Here is a running example:

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
import time
import sys

def progress(i,tot,bar_length=20):
    percent=(float(i)+1.0)/tot
    hashes='#' * int(round(percent*bar_length))
    spaces=' ' * (bar_length - len(hashes))
    sys.stdout.write("\rPercent:[{0}] {1}%".format(hashes + spaces, int(round(percent * 100)))+"    "+str(i+1)+"/"+str(tot))
    sys.stdout.flush()

t0 = time.time()

tf = t0 + 3600*24*365*10 # ten years

time_step = 2*3600.0 # 2 hours

span = int(ceil((tf-t0)/time_step))

A=[t0]
while A[-1]<tf:
    A.append(t0+len(A)*time_step/3) # 40 min time interval
B=[t0]
while B[-1]<tf:
    B.append(t0+len(B)*time_step/10) # 12 min time interval

A=np.array(A[:int(0.75*len(A))]) # shorten the list of A times
B=np.array(B[:int(len(B)/4)]+B[int(len(B)/4)+10800:]) # put a 3 month gap somewhere in the B list

tmin = t0
tempA = [[] for i in range(span)]
print 'Fill tempA bins with indices of times from A'
for i in range(span):
    progress(i,span)
    tmax = tmin+time_step
    times = A[(A>=tmin) & (A<tmax)]
    times_ID=np.nonzero(np.in1d(A,times))[0]
    tempA[i] = [j for j in times_ID]
    tmin = tmax
print '\nA has',len([i for i in tempA if i!=[]]),'intervals of',time_step,'seconds with data between t0 and tf\n'

tmin = t0
tempB = [[] for i in range(span)]
print '\nFill tempB bins with indices of times from B, only when the corresponding bin in tempA is not empty'
for i in range(span):
    progress(i,span)
    tmax=tmin+time_step
    if len(tempA[i])>0:
        times = B[(B>=tmin) & (B<tmax)]
        if len(times)>0:
            times_ID = np.nonzero(np.in1d(B,times))[0]
            tempB[i] = [j for j in times_ID]
        tmin=tmax
print '\nB has',len([i for i in tempB if i!=[]]),'intervals of',time_step,'seconds with data matching A times\n'

print '\nOnly select matching bins from both lists'
tpA=[i for i in tempA if i!=[] and tempB[tempA.index(i)]!=[]] # Matching indices for data in A
tpB=[i for i in tempB if i!=[] and tempA[tempB.index(i)]!=[]] # Matching indices for data in B
```

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: @wwii The example I gave isn't a minimal running example, I'll look into editing that. But yes my code works.

Comment: @wwii I added a running example, I use python 2.7